# MS Access VBA Data import for non-std file extensions

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am struggling to find the code I need to import a file into an access table.

It is a straight forward text file import however, the source file comes from a third party system and therefore the file extension is not the usual .txt file extension.

Instead the file is presented as ".ZZ;1"

This means that in order to import into access, I have to manually change the file extension before performing the import.

I wonder if there was a way to import the file (using VBA) with its given extension?

Or perhaps there is a piece of code which will allow me to change the file extension to something that access can read before I run my import script.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save yourself some grief by renaming the file to a standard extension (.txt or .csv) before importing it.

To rename: use the [Name Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264639.aspx)

e.g.

```
strNewName = Replace(strPathFile, ".ZZ;1", ".txt")
Name strPathFile As strNewName
```

or if you don't want to change the original file, use the [FileCopy Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s1c774y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), or [FileSystem.CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265015%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: Bingo!! Thanks a million. I had suspected this was the way to go, but always good to get a second opinion.

Put this before my import code and it worked a treat.

Many thanks